# How do I stop a sentinel value from being read into an array when determining total and average of the array?

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop, sentinel

I am not sure how to stop my sentinel value from being read into my array which is causing an error with my total and average calculation. Can anyone help?

Here is the while loop:

```
while (grade != -1)
{
    cin >> grade;
    gradesArray[count] = grade;
    total += gradesArray[count];
    average = total / count;
    count++;
}

cout << "You have entered " << count << " grades." << endl;
cout << "The average of these grades is " << average << endl;
```

Comment: Uh,test for it before you insert it.

Comment: And if you use a fixed-length array, make sure that `count` does not exceed the bounds of the array (and that you increment `count` *before* you calculate the new `average`). Otherwise, use a dynamic array instead, like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

`while (std::cin >> grade && grade != -1)`

Comment: This definitely works but for some reason my average comes out too high. If I enter 5 consecutive 23's and my average comes out as 28.5... Any idea as to why?

Comment: Compute the av rage after you increment the count.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my modified code, but the average outputs an average that is too high.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int count = 0, grade = 0;
double total = 0, average;
const int numGrades = 20;
int gradesArray[numGrades];

cout << "Welcome to the grade calulator!" << endl;
cout << "Enter up to twenty grades, when done enter -1: " << endl;


while (cin >> grade && grade != -1)
{
    gradesArray[count] = grade;
    total += gradesArray[count];
    average = total / count;
    ++count;
}

cout << "You have entered " << count << " grades." << endl;
cout << "The average of these grades is " << average << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```